# MATLAB AppDesign: Tracking ListBox double click

Tags: matlab, listbox

The ListBox element contains the callback-function:

- ValueChangedFcn

The `ValueChagedFcn` only tracks changes made to the listbox, thus if one select an item from the listbox and clicks it again, no event is triggered. Is it possible to track if an already selected item is once again clicked?

Comment: Other than a second call to the `ValueChangedFcn`? (Why is this not adequate?)

Comment: See https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/96424-how-can-i-execute-a-double-click-callback-without-executing-the-single-click-callback-in-my-matlab-g to track a double-click

Comment: @Wolfie It is not adequate because I need to add a double-click feature to a specific listbox (the app I'm working on contains more than one). And I'm fairly sure that `ValueChangedFcn` does something similar to `if event_new == event_old; return;`.Thus, I cen't track a double click. And I can't create my own `ValueChangedFcn` as it is prohibited by the nature of Matlab's appDesigner. And I can't change the actual sourcefile, since that would change the remaining ListBoxes in my app.

Comment: @marsei how would you associate that with a listbox? My problem isn't writing a double click function, my problem is to associate it with a listbox ;-)

Comment: Fair enough... as an aside, a double click "feature" on a listbox sounds like questionable UX design off the bat, probably easier to just have a button or right click menu. Without context in your question it's impossible to elaborate on that though.

Comment: You can add the proposed code in the `listboxX_ButtonDownFcn` function - setting the `pause` to `(1)` is better for the tracking

Comment: @Wolfie The listbox in question contains a list of folders and is meant to act as a browser. It shows all folders in a certain location. If you double click an item, the list will update to show the content of the folder, unless the item you clicked was a file. In that case you will be taken to another app that will use the data from the file in question. If the app-designer has another feature to accommodate this, I would be happy to use it. But so far, I haven't found any.

Comment: Like I said, just use a button beside your drop down for "open folder" / "choose folder" / "open file", voila - a much clearer UX. Or a [tree](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uitree.html)

Comment: @Wolfie Thanks for your input. That's what I have atm, but I honestly prefer the double-click.

Comment: @marsei I can't add the ButtonDownFcn. It's not a part of the listbox in the app designer. https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.control.listbox-properties.html

Comment: I think I'll try to add a listener instead. Hopefully that will get me where I want to go. I will add a solution if I get there. Else I'll stick with Wolfie's idea. Thanks for the help! :)